How to add function definitions to hover in a custom VSCode language extension?
I'm trying to add support for a language in Visual Studio Code using TypeScript. I'm new to VSCode extension development, and I've run into a bit of a problem.
I've managed to add a Hover that shows where something is defined. But now I want to add function definitions when hovering over and got stuck on how to do this or maybe how it's usually done? I've seen someone make a .json file and take it from there, but is this the right approach?
I've tried searching through some other projects that also add support for a custom language but they mostly seem to be leaving this feature out…
I'd really appreciate any help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Is this answer something you can use? It's about creating a DefinitionProvider.

ohh okay this makes much more sense now, thanks a lot!!
